# IBehavior and Caliburn Micro, references

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro, behavior, win-universal-app

Im building Windows Universal app (for windows phone) and im trying to use behaviors. The app uses Caliburn micro 2.0 framework.

Behavior is like this:

```
public class ProgressIndicatorBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
   ...
}
```

In my view, I use the behavior like this:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:ProgressIndicatorBehavior IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

When I try to build this app, I get the following error:

> Error 2   The type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.IBehavior' exists in
>   both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll'
>   and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKNative\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.winmd'  ...

How should I set the app references, right now I have added Behaviors SDK, Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions and Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

completely skimmed over your problem.  The 2 Microsoft.XAML.* files are the behaviors..  Remove the reference to Behavior SDK and you should be good.!